# Angular2, get data from REST call

Tags: json, rest, angular

I'm triyng to get data from json file by a id, by I'm getting all the content.
Here the JSON:

```
[
{ "id": "1", "name": "Carlos", "apellidos":"López", "edad":"30", "ciudad":"Hospitalet" },
{ "id": "2", "name": "Arantxa", "apellidos":"Pavia", "edad":"24", "ciudad":"Barcelona" },
{ "id": "3", "name": "Didac" , "apellidos":"Pedra", "edad":"muchos", "ciudad":"Cornellà" },
{ "id": "4", "name": "Daniel" , "apellidos":"Farnos", "edad":"nolose", "ciudad":"Barcelona" }
]
```

Service:

```
private usersUrl = 'app/users.json'; 
getUser(id: String): Observable<User>{
    let body = JSON.stringify(
      {
        "token": "test",
        "content": {
            "id": id
          }
        }
   );
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({
        headers: headers,
        body : body
      });

    return this.http.get(this.usersUrl, options)
        .map(res => res.json()).catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Angular Component:

```
ngOnInit(){ 

    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        let id = +params['id'];
        this.apiService.getUser(id).subscribe( (res) => { console.log(res); } );            
    }) 

}
```

Console.log:

```
Array[4]0: Object1: Object2: Object3: Objectlength: 4__proto__: Array[0]
```

Is the JSON bad?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't filter the result by id.

```
.map(res => res.json())
.map(x > x.find(x => x.id == id) // filter by selected id
.catch(this.handleError);
```